# How to set "custom" option to View

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, android-view

I'm trying to set the options in my class that extends `LinearLayout`, in public constructor with `(Context , AttributeSet)` I take attribute with `TypedArray`, having said that, I created a class with a method `Builder` and i'm setting the parameters to `View` with that class (in public constructor), all right if I call `Builder` before `setContentView(..)`, if I call it later I have `NullPointerException`.

Now the question is how can I change "attributes" to the `View` class after **setting** the layout to `MainActivity`?

In simple code works like this:

**MainActivity into onCreate(..):**

```
MyBuilder.set(new MyBuilder.Builder()
.setParam(...)
.setEtc(...)
.build());

setContentView(...);

MyObject obj = (MyObject) findViewById(R.id.myObject); 
//MyObject.java get param from MyBuilder.java and use it for setup MyObject

//Works!
```

**Here is what I want:**

```
setContentView(...);

//Do various op

MyBuilder.set(new MyBuilder.Builder()
.setParam(...)
.setEtc(...)
.build());

MyObject obj = (MyObject) findViewById(R.id.myObject);

//Params to MyObject is set after setContentView()

//With this flow I get NullPointerException in MyObject.java in reference to MyBuilder.java
```

**Simple flow explaination as it works now:**

[image]

**Here is what I want:**

[image]

**This is logcat:**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.michelelacorte.lib/it.michelelacorte.lib.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class it.michelelacorte.lib.MyObject
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2434)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class it.michelelacorte.lib.MyObject
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
        at it.michelelacorte.lib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class it.michelelacorte.lib.MyObject
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at it.michelelacorte.lib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at it.michelelacorte.lib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'float it.michelelacorte.lib.MyBuilder.getRadius()' on a null object reference
        at it.michelelacorte.lib.MyObject.<init>(MyObject.java:90)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
        at it.michelelacorte.lib.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the stacktrace?

Comment: It is necessary? @tynn

Comment: It states the reason why it's not working. Without it's not possible to find the error.

Comment: I'm sorry but the stacktrace not show me anything , I can post the logcat 
but I do not think much use .

Comment: But I tell you that is not important because it comes back to a get method of class Builder..

Comment: @tynn I've edit with logcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML resource you're setting with `setContentView()` contains a tag `<it.michelelacorte.lib.MyObject .../>`. In the constructor `MyObject.<init>()` you then get the instance of `MyBuilder` and use it to setup the layout.

But since you only initialize `MyBuilder` after setting the content view, you only get a `null` instance and thus a `NullPointerException`.

Instead create a setup method in `MyObject`

```
public void setup() {
    MyBuilder builder = MyBuilder.get();
    if (builder != null) {
        // setup view with builder
    } else {
        // setup view defaults
    }
}
```

handling this and call it as appropiate in `onCreate()`

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject) findViewById(R.id.myObject);
obj.setup();
```

and the constructor itself

```
public MyObject() {
    super(...);
    setup();
}
```

Comment: Yeah it works, NullPointerException doesn't show!, but the object is created without "custom" attribute, it's empty! Why?

Comment: Ok MyBuilder is always null..! it's strange

Comment: @MicheleLacorte is it working with your old setup. Did you call `obj.setup()` after setting up the builder?

Comment: Yes! after creating MyObject

Comment: So what exactly is the issue then? Did you log or debug the behavior of your code?

Comment: When i call MyBuilder.set(new MyBuilder.Builder().setParam(...).build()); this is not set so setup method always go on else statement

Comment: You saved my time! I missed a simple check!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using `LayoutInflater` class, `createView` method.

methods signature is  `createView(name, prefix, attrs)` where `attrs` is instance of `AttributeSet`

here is some short documentation about this method, 
[more about LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html)

- **Parameters**:

  - name The full name of the class to be instantiated.
  - attrs The XML attributes supplied for this instance.
  - prefix
- **Returns**:

  - View The newly instantiated `view`, or null.
- **Throws**:

  - ClassNotFoundException
  - InflateException

try to use it in this way

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
inflater.createView(name, prefix, attrs);
```

you want to use it in `MainActivity` so i'm sure no problems occurs when you define `LayoutInflater`

but if you had any problem about it, comment on this post and i'll guide you how to do that.

Comment: i do this: inflater.inflate(R.id.layoutName, this, true) and everything works fine if the Builder for the options is done before setContentView in MainActivity , but if I try to do it after NullPointerException in references to the class Builder!

Comment: in your class that extends `LinearLayout` just put this constructor  `(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` and remove other ones,

Comment: is already so!! , look at the updated application perhaps you understand better